# CMD ejecuta tareas en ventana aparte ¿como hacer para que vuelva a ejecutarlas en ventana principal?

Tags: python, django, cmd

Trabajando con Django en el CMD de pronto ahora ejecuta todos los procesos en una ventana aparte causándome varios inconvenientes.

Necesito que vuelva a realizaros en la ventana original como lo hizo siempre.

Elegí para ilustrar el caso la típica función `python manage.py runserver`.

Las imágenes hablan por si solas, así era su funcionamiento normal;

[cmd1](https://s32.postimg.org/oz9tfe0d1/cmd1.jpg)

Así funciona actualmente:

[cmd](https://s31.postimg.org/y3xpft4gb/cmd.jpg)

Las imágenes son solo para ilustrar el problema pero corresponden a 2 pc's diferentes.

Esto me acurrió en una de ellas y no encuentro como solucionarlo. No tengo recuerdo de haber hecho ningún cambio drástico, ni actualización.

---

Quiero contar que tuve algunas novedades respecto  este tema aunque no he logrado dar con el "quid" de la cuestión todavía han habido avances. Se los comento para que pueda ayudar a alguien que le suceda lo mismo o intentemos entre los interesados llegar al fondo de este problema.

- Desinstalé e instalé nuevamente Python 3.5 y el problema momentáneamente se solucionó. Eso me lleva a observar que el problema tiene que ver con alguna configuración de python y no con algo relacionado a Django como pensé inicialmente.
- Los desarrollos que llevo en entorno separado (con `virtualenv`) siguieron ejecutándose en ventana aparte igualmente. Los proyectos standar volvieron a la normalidad.
- Tras intentar instalar `Pillow --> pip install Pillow`. Esto se ejecuta en la ventana CMD principal con normalidad, al final de la instalación surge un error referido a `zlib is required disabled with the --disable-zlib flag`, (algo así). Luego de esto todo se ejecuta en ventana aparte nuevamente...
- En el ejecutable de instalación Python elijo reparar la instalación --> comandos de `manage.py`  vuelven a la normalidad. Comandos de `pip` siguen en ventana aparte.

Esto es lo principal, no me quiero extender con detalles menores. Ya estoy frustrado.

Comment: ¿Qué has cambiado para que el comportamiento sea diferente?, ¿es otra máquina?, ¿has cambiado el código?, ¿ha cambiado el sistema operativo?,... Al menos, la versión de Django cambia de la primera imagen a la segunda. Si pones el código de tu *manage.py* quizá se pueda ver algo por ahí.

Comment: Hola @kikocorreoso, las imágenes son solo para ilustrar el problema pero corresponden a 2 pc's diferentes. Esto me acurrió en una de ellas y no encuentro como solucionarlo. No tengo recuerdo de haber hecho ningún cambio drástico, mismo SO, misma versión de django etc...

Comment: Quiero aclarar: de seguro he metido el dedo en algo que hizo que cambie su funcionamiento normal, solo no tendría por que hacerlo, claro está. Valla a saber dios que hice para que ello ocurra... solo he trabajado en entorno de Django pero no veo por que ello modificaría el funcionamiento de el CMD. Ojalá alguien sepa :)

Comment: quién y porqué da un voto negativo sin comentario? me parece injusto y desconsiderado.

Comment: Totalmente :( estoy indignado. Leí y me esforcé por redactar bien esta vez...

Comment: prueba `python manage.py runserver` en lugar de `manage.py runserver`. Mira si el ejecutable de Python está en tu **PATH**. Comprueba qué programa está asociado a los ficheros con extensión *.py*. Sin más información es difícil saber qué está pasando.

Comment: Ahí probé pero no hubo caso. Sigue ejecutando en ventana aparte... También verifiqué eso que me dices kikocorreoso, está todo en orden.

Comment: 2 cosas. 1 - @PA. los usuarios son libres de puntuar positiva o negativamente según sus opiniones, yo intento siempre poner comentarios para explicar le por qué pero no es obligatorio (y a veces yo mismo no lo hago cuándo creo que no merece la pena) 2 - Christ intenta hacer un reset de tu configuración de la cmd siguiendo este link: http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/228214-reset-cmd-default-settings.html

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con:

```
start /B manage.py runserver
```

Si con esto no va, es que creas una nueva ventana de forma explícita en algún lugar.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que se comenta, en los entornos virtuales que has ido creando para cada proyecto tienes aún el problema.

Para resolverlo, propongo que crear un nuevo entorno virtual para cada proyecto e instalar en cada nuevo entorno lo necesario.